# How can i pass data from child to parent on click which has no connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a map application on react.js . In this application I just want to send the lat and lng of Markers component onClicked to App Component. But the App.js isn't connected to Markers.js. Markers.js is connected to CurrentLocationMap.js. So, anyone can tell me how to send latlng value of Markers.js to App.js .

[image: File tree of the project]

```
export function Markers(props) {
 

  function onMarkerClick(e) {
    const latlng = e.target._latlng;
    console.log(latlng);

  }

  return (
  
      <Marker
        eventHandlers={{ click: onMarkerClick }}
        position={props.position}
        icon={icon}
      >
        <Popup>
          <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>My Location</p>

          <Link to="/get-position-img">
            <button style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>Show Image</button>
          </Link>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>

  );
}
```

```
function App() {

// this is where is want to get the latlng of Markers.js


return (
    <Router>
      <Map />

      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/upload-img"
          element={<ShowImgFromSide url="http://localhost:5000/uploaded-img" />}
        />
      </Routes>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/get-position-img"
          element={
            <ShowImgFromSide url={`http://localhost:5000/get-img-position/`} />
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: As your application grows you may want to start looking into state management libraries like Jotai, Zustand, or Recoil.

Answer (score 0):

To send information from a child component to it ascendant element whether its parent or not, just create a `state` in the component you want to receive the information. Pass it to `CurrentLocationMap.jsx` and from it to `Markers.jsx`. And finally, set the `latlng` value to another.

`App.jsx`:

```
const [latlng, setLatlng] = useState()
```

Just pass it to the `CurrentLocationMap.jsx`

```
<CurrentLocationMap latlng={latlng} setLatlng={setLatlng} />
```

In the `Markers.jsx` set the value of `latlng` with `setLatlng` depending of the logic of your component:

```
setLatlng(latlng)
```